# NGINX - Websocket client support

Tags: nginx, libwebsockets

A quick question, Does Nginx support websocket client.

I have a webserver that uses NGINX and i use a websocket server for which NGINX acts as proxy. In the same port , can i use websocket client to initiate a connection with the external websocket server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does (since 1.3.13).

Have a look at the docs [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) and an example setup [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)